# Koha Installation in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

i am installing koha -3.12.00 in ubuntu 12.04 and i am following bellow link.

**https://github.com/colinsc/koha/blob/master/INSTALL.ubuntu.12.04..**

i am getting an error while running the command
 $ ./misc/sax_parser_print.pl.**

Please find the error below

****BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./misc/sax_parser_print.pl line 6**.
the below code is sax_parser_print.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# check the current SAX Parser
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser();
print "Koha wants something like:
XML::LibXML::SAX::Parser=HASH(0x81fe220)
```

You have:

```
$parser\n";
print "Looks " .
($parser =~ /^XML::LibXML::SAX::Parser=HASH/ ?
"good.\n" : "bad, check INSTALL.* documentation.\n");
[XML::LibXML::SAX::Parser]**
```

According to the document provided we need to do changes in the .ini file to by replacing it

```
[XML::LibXML::SAX::Parser]
```

but when i save i am getting the error like

```
**No such file or directory**
```

so i tried in cpan shell and apt-get install to install this module after install also

```
 **No such file or directory**
```

so please provide solution for this

Answer (score 2):

The Koha project provides Debian packages that can be installed on Ubuntu; try following these instructions:

http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages

Installing the koha-common package is *the* recommended way of setting up a production system on Debian or Ubuntu.

However, as far as the instructions you are following is concerned (if you still want to follow that option, but I repeat, it is not the recommended one) the error message sounds like the libxml-sax-perl package was not installed.  I suggest running step 1.6 again to install Koha's dependencies, then verify that libxml-sax-perl is installed.